# How to apply NSG to Could Service?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

I have 2 `VNet` and have connected them using `VPN` as side to side. Each `Vnet` has a cloud service. I need apply `NSG` to `VNet` to allow http call between cloud services but deny any http request from internet. Is there any way to configure that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely. The only specificity is that you are in the case of a generation 1, or classic Azure infrastucture (Cloud Service) but you will put in place NSGs to Subnets (and not to VNETs).

Take [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-classic-ps/) for reference, but you can do it now in the Azure portal also (the new one).